# How can I update R using conda?

Tags: r, anaconda

I installed `Rstudio` using `anaconda`. I think the `R` was also installed alongside with it (but I read somewhere that `Rstudio` doesn't come with `R`: Tell me if I am wrong).

From terminal: `which R` shows :`/home/simo/anaconda3/bin/R`.

I tried that:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo echo "deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

but doesn't upgrade the version of R (still `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"`)

At the first place I want to install: `dashHtmlComponents`,  a `dash` library.

```
> install.packages("dashHtmlComponents")
Warning message:
package ‘dashHtmlComponents’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1) 
>
```

But from the dash documentation I read that at least version 3.0.2 of R is required.

What is wrong?

Comment: RStudio is just an IDE for R. It does not install with R, or vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah ,That's what i was expecting .Thank you

Comment: Probably you have two versions of R: /home/[user]/anaconda3/envs/[env]/bin/R and in /usr/bin/R You have updated one, but not the one linked to your conda env?. Sorry other users voted you down (-2), they did not understand you. I added +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what OS you are on how you would go about doing that. The particular methods for Windows and MacOS are laid out on this [page](http://www.byperth.com/2017/11/01/3-methods-update-r-rstudio-windows-mac/).

As far as if you have R (which it appears you do, but nonetheless), you can run `install r-essentials --yes` in the terminal (Mac) or Anaconda Prompt (PC). In Linux you can follow the steps [here](https://evanwill.github.io/_drafts/notes/r-linux.html).

Once you do either of these, you should be able to use `install.packages('dashHtmlComponents')`. I am using R version 3.6.2 and it installs just fine.

Comment: I'm using linux 19.3 ,so i can't use the `installr` package and `sudo apt-get install r-essentials --yes` says `E: Unable to locate package r-essential` ,i think that the problem is it cannot locate the R since it under `Anaconda` .. Thank you

Comment: You should use `install r-essentials` inside Anaconda. Maybe try this: https://evanwill.github.io/_drafts/notes/r-linux.html

Comment: This answer is somewhere between confusing and misleading as `installr` is _only for Windows_ as [its DESCRIPTION clearly shows](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html).

Comment: Your first comment is also confused. There is no "Linux 19.3".  Maybe that is your Mint release, I can't tell. In any event, _mixing the package management of your distribution AND conda_ is a genuinely bad idea.  Stick with either your distro for R, or with Conda.  Not half-and-half.

Comment: The single best resource, in my mind, for R on (.deb based) Linux is the r-sig-debian list for Debian, Ubuntu, and their derivatives.  Try it, it's free anyway.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for issuing this correction. I misspoke originally and have corrected it.

Comment: @ToddBurys No worries, it happens. Easy to overlook details. That's why it is good we do this in the open with the means to correct and edit.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I meant `linux mint 19.3` thank you for correcting ,So how can i just update the R in Anaconda if that possible ,Thank you